# Make ID field automatic in Sharepoint/Powerapp

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a PowerApp that is supposed to add data to a SharePoint list. The SharePoint list has an ID column that should not be filled out by the user but should increase automatically with each new row of data.

Right now the ID field in the App has to filled out by the user, but this leads to duplicates in the SharePoint list.

How can i make the ID value to increase by 1 after each data input from a PowerApp to a SharePoint List, without any user input?

Answer (score 0):

I use the SharePoint List's ID column and simply show the user the value (read only).
The ID number will increase **after** you save the new list item in Sharepoint.
Make sure the *datacard* for that SharePoint field in PowerApps has *DisplayMode=View*